# Ios - Wrong architecture building WebRTC

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc, armv7, arm64

I'm building WebRTC for iOS. To do that, I'm using the following bash script:

```
# Set flags to compile in arm64
export GYP_GENERATORS="ninja"
export GYP_DEFINES="build_with_libjingle=1 build_with_chromium=1 libjingle_objc=1 OS=ios target_arch=arm64"
export GYP_GENERATOR_FLAGS="output_dir=out_ios_arm64"
export GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1

# Generate metadata for compile
gclient runhooks

# Compile webRTC in Release and verbose mode
ninja -v -C src/out_ios_arm64/Release-iphoneos AppRTCDemo
```

In the same machine and the same dir, I have compiled for `armv7` and now when I try to build with the code above, the library is compiled for `armv7`. Maybe I have some metadata info in my dir that I'm not removing or something but I understand that if I set **target_arch=arm64** in my GYP_DEFINES I should see my library compiled for this arch. Any idea  what could be happening?

P.D: I need to build for both (`armv7` and `arm64`) in order to generate with lipo an universal lib.

Comment: Did you perhaps check in src/out_ios_armv7/ ? Instead of in src/out_ios_arm64/

Comment: @Kevin yes, of course

Comment: Well, then there's your problem, the armv7 lib ends up in src/out_ios_armv7, but when you build for another architecture, you have to get the lib from another directory (src/out_ios_arm64 in your case)

Comment: @kevin when I'm building I can see compilation line to ensure that -arch is armv7, not arm64, is not a directory issue.